# Single database for many domains approach

Tags: mysql, database

Good morning.

I have to build a system (php/mysql) that run in a 20 domains for 20 different cities (for example). The system that run in this 20 domains is identical, the database too.

**My issue is**: I pretend to create a single database to serve this 20 domains, controlling the cities by something like city_id.
I wish to know if this is the best practice, or if the right way is create one database to each city/domain.

The domains are hosted in the same server, the core system is out of public_html directory.

```
/mysystem_classes
/public_html/city1.com
/public_html/city2.com
/public_html/city3.com
/public_html/city20.com
```

To serve images, css and js I will work with something like a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would setup just one virtual host, install your application there and let all the domains point to that software. Which domain points to which website is not specified on the server level, but on the application level in that case.

[TYPO3](http://typo3.org/) for example works like that when building multiple sites with one instance of TYPO3 and the used MySQL database. (using TypoScript or the backend configuration to define which domain belongs to which site-ID)

[Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) has a multisite feature, which could be set up easily to use several subdomains. It uses one database and a single software instance but can deliver multiple blogs to different domains. (e.g. city1.example.org, city2.example.org). You will need to setup a wildcard domain (i.e. *.exqample.org) to let all possible subdomains point to the single vHost. This is similar to how the basic Wordpress.com-Blogs work. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for [Mysql replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html).